# Can you guys help me? Why did the bootstrap card stick left in mobile view

Tags: html, css, web, frameworks, bootstrap-5

I did anything but it still won't work. Maybe you guys can help me?
Here are some photos.

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ginvk.png)

[AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23c5a.png)

I want the card to stay in the middle when I view it in mobile size.
maybe there are some codes that I miss?
I would like to thank you so much if someone solved it for me.
I'm still new using bootstrap and not really pro at HTML and CSS.
here are the codes.

```
<!-- Members Card -->
<div class="container my-5">

  <h1 class="text-center mb-3"><b>MEMBERS</b></h1>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- Jennie -->
      <div class="col-md col-sm">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
            <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Jisoo -->
      <div class="col-md col-sm">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
            <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Lisa -->
      <div class="col-md col-sm">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
            <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Rose -->
      <div class="col-md col-sm">
        <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
            <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!--close tag for row-->

  </div> <!--close tag for d-flex -->
</div> <!--close tag for container-->
<!-- End Members Card -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add classnames `d-flex justify-content-center` near every `col-md col-sm`

(i.e)  `col-md col-sm d-flex justify-content-center`

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the `.card` inside media query for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap, you need add the class `mx-auto` to each `div class="card"`and that's it.

Source: [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Copy this code, this is your fixed code:

```
<h1 class="text-center mb-3"><b>MEMBERS</b></h1>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Jennie -->
    <div class="col-md col-sm">
      <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jisoo -->
    <div class="col-md col-sm">
      <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Lisa -->
    <div class="col-md col-sm">
      <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Rose -->
    <div class="col-md col-sm">
      <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 15rem;">
        <img src="{image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title"><b>{Name}</b></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{desc}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline-secondary text-white">show more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!--close tag for row-->

</div> <!--close tag for d-flex -->
```